# What is Audrey Weasley's maiden name?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Percy married a woman named Audrey. But very little info is given about her. To start, we don't even know her maiden name! Do you have any knowledge about her?

Comment: "We know that Percy married a woman named Audrey." Do we? It's news to me. Is this from *Cursed Child*?

Comment: @F1Krazy [Pottermore family tree](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-weasley-family-tree), which is kind of the most complete it gets for these matters, and does not mention a maiden name.

Comment: Side comment, but I've seen you posting a lot these days. If you're interested in participating, you should register your account :) (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/398063))

Comment: It is not Cursed Child. Do you read Pottermore? It is a great site, all canon! Here is a link to the Weasley Family tree: https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-weasley-family-tree                                Once you are on the site, click on the plus symbols to read more.

Comment: @Smartie - Anything from Pottermore which doesn't say "by J.K Rowling" in big letters is just recycled material put together by the Pottermore team. Nothing in "Features" a canon source. In this case the information comes from a 2007 documentary titled *J.K. Rowling: A Year in the Life*, where she talked a bit about the future of the characters. I'll post an answer soon with the exact quote.

Answer (score 10):

## Unknown

The best mention I can see to Audrey is in the Pottermore article on the [The Weasley family tree](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-weasley-family-tree) and here it just mentions a first name with no maiden name. The [text version](https://www.pottermore.com/about/the-weasley-family-tree-text-version) isn't much better and still refers to her as just Audrey.

> AUDREY
>
> Audrey was married to Percy Weasley. Together they had two daughters named Molly and Lucy. It is unknown if Audrey ever worked for the Ministry but, thanks to her husband, no doubt she knew all their rules and regulations in detail.

Comment: Indeed, "Audrey Weasley" has a better ring than "Audrey Unknown".

Comment: @Jenayah Although Mr and Mrs Unknown has quite a ring to it.

Comment: Ooooh, ever heard of "Unknown Artist"? Think they're related? I've got all their CDs, but hey, you gotta admit "Unknown Album" is the best they've made!!!

Comment: I prefer Various Artists - the random sibling who couldn't spell their surname.

Comment: @Jenayah - No, but the [Unknown Comic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unknown_Comic) rocked. I should have realized he couldn't possibly be a muggle.

Comment: Be aware that this is a Pottermore/**featured** article.?if it’s not supported anywhere else it’s (as I’m assured by “HP experts”) almost certainly been made up by some random chump at Pottermore and isn’t anything canonical,

Comment: @Edlothiad - Yup, the source of this answer is just an article written by a no-name on Pottermore's editorial team, and which Pottermore didn't even consider preserving when they switched websites. Nothing in here comes directly from Rowling, it's at best a secondary source. Hence the fan wiki style phrasing like "it's unknown" and the fanfictiony speculation about her home life.

Answer (score 8):

### Unknown, but presumably a "Percy-like" name.

The only time Rowling has directly discussed Percy's wife is in the 2007 documentary, *J.K. Rowling: A Year in the Life*. As part of the documentary, Rowling drew out a family tree showing the main characters after book seven.

> [image]
>
> Percy married Audrey — Don't you think that's a very Percy-like wife's name? — And they had Molly and Lucy.
>
> <sub>[*J.K. Rowling: A Year in the Life*](https://youtu.be/Ij97LWo0I7s?t=1945) (This line appears at 32:36)</sub>

**The only comment given about Audrey was that she had a "Percy-like" name. It's possible that Rowling used similar criteria for choosing her maiden name.**

The day before the documentary aired, a low resolution scan of the family tree posted behind the secret door of Rowling's old website, where it remained until the site closed in 2012.

> [image]

Besides for these two places, Rowling has never as much as mentioned Audrey. Percy appears twice in the 2014 Quidditch World Cup writings, but nothing is said about his wife. (It's loosely implied though that he was still married.)

Comment: What's the evidence that Rowling ever even chose a maiden surname for Audrey? Your quote only says that her first name "Audrey" is Percy-like, which doesn't at all imply her surname would be too.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - No evidence, and it's likely she never picked one. But I've gathered all the actual canon sources for Audrey that exist, including JKR's explanation for why she picked that name. I don't think it's a big stretch to say she might to same for the surname. (e.g. Remus Lupin). It's not much but it's all that there is and the bold text in the middle of my answer sums it up.